# Join mesh in edit mode

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I joined two meshes into one Mesh. but in the edit mode, it still shows two.

I tried the following and still, it did not work.

1. tried to merge vertices in edit mode,
2. merge by distance in edit mode,
3. dissolve it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please share your file or use some images to explain your problem because right now I don't understand what is your exact problem

Comment: can see them now ??

Comment: You see two faces of one (joined) mesh. Do you want to merge these faces? If so, try to dissolve the edge between the faces, i assume you already merged overlapping vertices.